# node pull key value from object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this object with key / value pairs and I'm not able to figure out how to access the keys and values to console.log

```
[ { ETHBTC: '฿0.05864000', USD: '$391.36', ETHUSDT: '391.30' } ]
```

I've tried several ways to iterate and am not able to figure out.

Comment: this is an array, are you accessing its index before accessing the key/value pairs?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json help? Please show the code you have tried.

Comment: Please show us your attempts. There are many, many questions on Stack Overflow about this, including the aforementioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Comment: I had tried this to print
Promise.all([promise1]).then(function(_addField) {
 Object.keys(_addField).forEach(function(prop) {
 console.log(prop)
 console.log(_addField[prop])
});

Comment: and i get output of
{ ETHBTC: '฿0.05857600', USD: '$391.99', ETHUSDT: '391.53' }
Do I need to then loop again over this to pull out key / values

Comment: I was able to figure this out

Promise.all([promise1]).then(function(_addField) {
 Object.keys(_addField).forEach(function(prop) {
  Object.keys(_addField[prop]).forEach(function(key) {
   console.log(key)
   console.log(_addField[prop][key])
});

Thanks for the links, helped me understand.